# How should fields of a struct be accessed through a pointer to a pointer?

Tags: c

Say I have a function `f(struct_t** p)` that manipulates a struct `s` through `p`. `f` calls a function `g(struct_t** p)` that will reallocate `s` such that the caller of `f` will still be able to access `s` through `*p` after `f` returns. I can think of three ways to handle access to fields of `s` in `f`:

- Assign `struct_t* q = *p` at the beginning of `f` for more readable access to `s` through `q->field_name` rather than `(*p)->field_name`, and reassign `q` to `*p` after each call to `g(p)`.
- Access fields of s using `(*p)->field_name` throughout `f` and sacrifice readability.
- `#define` `q` to `(*p)` for the duration of `f`.

Which of these would be best? If none of them are ideal, how should fields of `s` be accessed in `f`?

Comment: I'm voting to close here as primarily opinion based. No offense intended, but for example, my opionion on `(*p)->field_name` is that it's perfectly readable...

Comment: probably going to get closed for not really being a specific enough question... and for being confusing with p's and s's...

Comment: My mistake if it's not a suitable question. I've always found `(*p)->field_name` difficult to read when nested in other sets of parentheses (and a pain to type), but that might just be me.

Comment: @jschmidt that's the problem with opinion-based questions, it depends on who you ask. I would argue writing `(*p)->field_name` is best because it follows the principle of least surprise. A C programmer will understand it without a) looking up preprocessor macros oder b) following a lot of assignments -- like in your other options. (btw note I didn't vote here -- it's good to think about such things, but it's not a good match for a Q&A site ...)

Comment: BTW, as it stands now, you got reps (upvotes) for a question that's off-topic according to site policies. So although it's not a good match here, it's still a good question! I hope you take this as an incentive to join the community actively :)

Comment: You may also consider `(**p).field_name`.